# Media query for all hi-res devices. Load only hi-res photos

Tags: mobile, media-queries

I have a page with a lot of img. I try to put the img in background to have same img for hi-res devices and other img for non hi-res. I have 2 questions:

1. Is this media query up to date and useful for all new hi-res devices, Apple retina and the other new hi-res?. I am looking for just 1 media query for all devices. Is it possible?
2. In this case, the hi-res devices will load the non hi-res img too? If so, how to make hi-res devices load only hi-res photos?

HTML:

```
<div class="photo"> </div>
```

CSS:

```
.photo {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:980px; height:660px;

    background-image:url('img/normal/1.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    background-size:100%;
}

/* for all hi-res */
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), 
       (min-resolution: 144dpi){ 
.photo { background-image:url('img/2x/1.jpg'); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for High-res graphics

```
@media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
(min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
    #photo { background-image:url('img/2/1.jpg''); }
}
```

Or other high resolution graphics

```
@media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25), 
(min-resolution: 120dpi){ 
    #photo { background-image:url('img/1.25/1.jpg'); }
}


@media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3), 
(min-resolution: 124.8dpi){ 
    #photo { background-image:url('img/1.3/1.jpg'); }
}


@media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), 
(min-resolution: 144dpi){ 
    #photo { background-image:url('img/1.5/1.jpg'); }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps I did not explain well. I am asking : 1. Can I use one media query for all hi-res devices. 2. Does it load only hi-res photos